# Q-Q plot in one figure instead of 9 subplots python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, distribution, figure

I have a code in which I plot the Q-Q distribution of nine stocks (iN = 9). So I have one figure with 9 subplots. However, I want to have these 9 subplots into one big plot, so one figure. Currently my code is:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=6, ncols=2, figsize=(9,20))
ax= axes.flatten()
for i in range(iN):
    sm.qqplot((mY[i,:]), fit = True, line='q', ax=ax[i])
    ax[i].legend(asX2[i])
plt.savefig('NSE_mY_QQplot_norm.jpg', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

So I changed the code to this:

```
 fig= plt.figure(figsize=(9,20))
 for i in range(iN):
     sm.qqplot((mY[i,:]), fit = True, line='q', ax=ax[i])
     ax[i].legend(asX2[i])
 plt.savefig('NSE_mY_QQplot_norm.jpg', bbox_inches='tight')
 plt.show()
```

But then I do not get a figure at all. Only this note after I run it:
      matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x1c22325828

Help is appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried using `plt.subplots()` with `nrows = 1` and `ncols = 1`? You get of course only one element in `axes`, so you don't have to flatten it and index it.

Answer (score 0):

I am two reputation short of being able to comment so I will leave this as an answer. A similar question was asked a couple days ago (far after yours) that appears to give the result you wanted: [Python: Multiple QQ-Plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55142882/python-multiple-qq-plot)